# How to use cache with simplepie

Tags: cache, simplepie

According to the docs, if you want to cache results for a fetch of RSS feeds with simplepie, you do this:

```
 add_filter( 'wp_feed_cache_transient_lifetime' , 'return_7200' );
 $feed = fetch_feed( $feed_url );
 remove_filter( 'wp_feed_cache_transient_lifetime' , 'return_7200' );
```

My question is if I want to cache the results for several feed urls (by looping through an array), would I really want to add and remove the filter for each pass of the loop (wouldn't that cause separate entries in the cache for each feed) or should I do this:

```
add_filter( 'wp_feed_cache_transient_lifetime' , 'return_7200' );

for ($i=.......){
  $feed = fetch_feed( $feed_url );
}

 remove_filter( 'wp_feed_cache_transient_lifetime' , 'return_7200' );
```

Frankly (and this might be obvious), I'm confused as to how this caching works since all I've seen are examples for a single feed, rather than multiple feeds.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The example your using from the codex  adds and removes it (probably not something you want to do), and is not very clear.

*By default WordPress will cache the feed for 12 hours* using `wp_feed_cache_transient_lifetime`, the actual code WP uses for 12 hours is  `$lifetime = 43200`

If you want to alter the cache time globally for all simplepie feeds, you can add new time to the filter,

```
//change cache to 24hrs
add_filter( 'wp_feed_cache_transient_lifetime', create_function('$a', 'return 86400;') );
```

If instead you want specific feeds to have different cache times, you can use the `$url` parameter in the filter.

```
add_filter( 'wp_feed_cache_transient_lifetime', 'change_feed_speed' );

function change_feed_speed( $lifetime, $url ) {

    if( 'http://mysite.org/some-feed.rss' == $url )
        return 86400;

    return $lifetime;
}
```